# Why won't Java's BufferedReader act like Objective-C's NSData?

Tags: java, objective-c, encoding, nsdata, bufferedreader

I'm developing an application running on Android and iOS devices. For this app I need to get an XML stream from a URL. This XML is not really safe, because some lines, for example :

> Révélation

Will become :

> R�v�lation

**Of course** I know the best thing to do is to fix the XML generator script. But I'm only working as a developer for a firm and don't have access to it, so for the moment I'm trying to do what I can with what I have.

Now here is the reason of this topic. When I put this data in an Objective-C's NSData object :

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

And then try to read every byte :

```
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%d",byteData[i]);
}
```

It correctly displays the int value of the char, special character or not. Then I just have to handle `(unichar)byteData[i]` to solve it.

No with Java and Android, I'm trying to do a basic BufferedReader operation.

```
URL myURL = new URL(url);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream()));
```

Then print every char's int one by one :

```
int i;
while((i = in.read()) != -1) System.out.print(i);
```

But with Java, by doing this I immediately get the replacement char's id (65533) instead of the good one, and can't manage to replace it.

Any idea? Thanks for reading me.

Comment: In Java, there's no need to create a `BufferedReader` for reading XML. Run the XML parser directly on the `InputStream`, it will handle the encoding by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

- **InputStreams** are for bytes, binary data.
- **Readers** are for characters, String, text.

The InputStreamReader bridges this conceptual difference, *saying which encoding the binary data is in,* and has an optional parameter for the encoding. The default encoding is that of the current platform - so not very portable.